# Sending sysrq through the picocom or TigerVNC

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, console

I have some VM on qemu, which occasionally freezes.
Thus I need some way to send [sysrq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_request) to my VM. I use both TigerVNC and picocom, but the appropriate hotkeys (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) don't work. Obviously, in this case <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> sends sysrq to my host Linux, not VM.

So is there a way to send sysrq to VM through the picocom terminal or TigerVNC?

Seem that it's related to somehow sending "break" in case of picocom.

Comment: As a quick pointer, I believe that sending this keystroke may likely be possible using the Qemu monitor, using -telnet so the Qemu software acts as a telnet server (which can be set to listen to only localhost).

Comment: @TOOGAM it would be nice to see a brief example..

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [linux kernel documentation on SysRq](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/sysrq.rst).

per the document **On the serial console** it says

> *You send a BREAK, then within 5 seconds a command key.*

In the `picocom` man page we see

> C-backslash
>
> ```
>          Generate a break sequence on the serial line.
> ```

so for sending SIGTERM to all processes it'd be

`ctrl+a`+`ctrl+\`+`e`

Note when `picocom` shows you `** break sent **` that's a `picocom` output and not a response from linux.